# Classes with vector inside

Tags: python, list, class

```
class Gate():
   def _init_(self):
       self.Code=""
       self.Occupancy=False
       self.AircraftID=" "

class BoardingArea():
    def _init_(self):
        self.Name=""
        self.Schengen=False
        self.Gate=[]
```

So I have this 2 classes, boarding area has a vector with numerous gates, when I try to fill that vector inside the class I get an error I tried various things but none seem to work, any ideas?

```
n=10
B=BoardingArea()
while n>0:
            G=Gate()
            code=elementos[1] + str(n)
            G.Code=code
            B.Gate.append(G)
            n-=1
print B.__dict__

B.Gate.append(G)
AttributeError: BoardingArea instance has no attribute 'Gate'
```

Comment: ignore the code variable, it's part of a bigger code

Comment: It should be `__init__` (with two underscores before and after) not `_init_` (with only one underscore each)

Comment: Closing for typo. Your `_init_` methods are never called because they are not `__init__` methods.

Answer (score 4):

Change `_init_` to `__init__` (double underscore)

Comment: Just flag as typo and close

Comment: Already voted :)

Comment: I tried to fix the code as you suggested, but it doesn't work <script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/0W67UU" type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: @CIsForCookies You only fixed one of the inits, and not the one with the gates list.